# My desktop shortcut won´t execute

Tags: raspbian, python, sensor, gui, desktop

I created a GUI that tells me the temperature based on the temperature sensor I connected to the raspberry pi, that works fine, but then, I tried to do a desktop shortcut, and when I click on it, the Terminal opens for like a millisecond, and then it closes (I recorded it in slo-mo and noticed that it opened the normal terminal first, then the lxterminal and then a terminal with the name of my program, but after it opened that one, the terminal closed and nothing happened.), The code I made to create the shortcut was originally shorter than this one but after a lot of research I added many things, but it still wont open.
My code is the following:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Terminal=true
Name=Temperatura
Exec=lxterminal -e /home/pi/GUI_TMP.py
MultipleArgs=false
Type=Application
Category=Accesories
StartupNotify=true
Icon=/home/pi/Pictures/tmp.jpeg
Hidden=false
X-KeepTerminal=true
NoDisplay=false
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried calling the interpreter of the script instead of the script itself?, like this:

```
Exec=lxterminal -e python /home/pi/GUI_TMP.py
```

or

```
Exec=lxterminal -e /usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/GUI_TMP.py
```